# Basic Results about Linear ODEs...

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-equations

Essentially we are asked to prove these results about ODEs...

(i) If $F : I \rightarrow GL(n, R)$ satisfies the matrix ODE $F' = F A$ , then $ Det(F)$ satisfies
the scalar ODE $(Det(F))' = Tr(A) Det(F)$.

(ii) If $F : I \rightarrow GL(n, R)$ satisfies the matrix ODE $F' = F A$ and for some $t_0 \in I$
we have $F(t_0) \in GL(n, R)$, where $GL(n, R)$ denotes the group of invertible
matrices, then $F : I \rightarrow GL(n, R)$.

(iii) If $F : I \rightarrow GL(n, R)$ satisfies the matrix ODE $F' = F A$ and $Tr(A) = 0$ then
$Det (F(t))$ is constant in $t$. In particular, if $Det(F(t_0)) = 1$ then $Det (F(t)) = 1$
for all $t \in I$.

(iv) If $F : I \rightarrow GL(n, R)$ satisfies the matrix ODE $F' = F A$ and $A: I \rightarrow SO(n, R)$
takes values in skew-symmetric matrices, then $F^T
(t)F(t)$ is constant in $t$.
In particular, if $F(t_0) \in O(n, R)$ then $F : I → O(n, R)$. The analogous
statement holds for $F(t_0) \in SO(n, R$).

So I'm stuck on part i) I defined the matrices $F$ and $A$ as $2 \times 2$ matrices with lower case $f$ and $a$ with $f_{11}$ in top left spot for $F$ and $a_{22}$ in bottom right spot (the normal convention) for $A$. I calculated $Det(FA)$ and after some cancellations I found that to be ${f_{11}*a_{11}*f_{22}*a_{22} + f_{12}*a_{21}*f_{21}*a_{12}} - {f_{11}*a_{12}*f_{22}*a_{21} + f_{12}*a_{22}*f_{21}*a_{11}}$

Then I tried to calculate $Det(F)Tr(A)$ and found...

$|F|*Tr(A) = ({f_{11}*f_{22} - f_{12}*f_{21}})*(α_{11} + α_{22})$ but here I can already see that I'll get terms with only 3 things being multiplied (rather than four per term in the $Det(FA)$) I'm not sure if maybe I did something wrong with my computations (I doubled-checked and feel confident) or perhaps I'm missing some cancellation somewhere but I just don't see how to get these two things to equal one another. Any suggestions?

Comment: Also for number ii) is this basically saying that if there's a point t_0 for which F belongs to the group of invertible matrices (and thus is invertible at that point) and it satisfies F' = FA then F is an invertible matrix? I'm not sure how I could argue that. Or if I'm totally off base here can someone please assist?

Answer (score 0):

I will address i)

First, auxiliary lemma:

If $X\in C^1(I;\mathbb R^{n\times n})$ then
$$
\frac{\frac{d}{dt}\det X(t)}{\det X(t)}={\rm tr}\left(X'(t)X(t)^{-1}\right).\tag{$\ast$}
$$

to prove it consider
$$
X(t_0+h)=X(t_0)+hX'(t_0)+o(h).
$$
Take the determinant
$$
\det X(t_0+h)=\det X(t_0)\det(I+hX'(t_0)X^{-1}(t_0)+o(h)).
$$
Next, use the fact that 
$$
\det(I+h B+o(h))=1+h\,{\rm tr\,}B+o(h)\quad\mbox{(exercise!)}
$$
conclude that
$$
\det X(t_0+h)=\det X(t_0)(1+h{\,\rm tr}\left(X'(t_0)X^{-1}(t_0)\right)+o(h)),
$$
rearrange, divide by $h$ and take the limit $h\to 0$ to get the required formula.

Now from $F'=AF$ and $(\ast)$ you immediately get
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\det F(t)={\rm tr\,}A\det F(t).
$$

Comment: Oh I see.. there's a lemma about that which I hadn't known (my instructor expects us to do much of the work outside class). This all makes sense now.. I imagine then there are probably some other lemmas of theorems/facts that are to be utilized in proving the remaining facts. Can anyone perhaps provide me with a resource that might list some of these lemmas for matrix ODEs or theorems or what have you.. or if anyone has an idea about any other statements that need be used for the remaining problems please do share them as it will make my frantic searching of wikipedia less frantic. Thanks!

Comment: @KyleO'Connell Given (i) the rest should not be a problem.

Comment: So what you're saying is the rest of the questions rely on the fact that the derivative of the determinant equals the determinant of F times the trace of A? Well, so how could I use that to my advantage to show that if a matrix is a part of the General Linear group at t0 then it will be throughout the interval I?

Comment: Let $x(t)=\det F(t), a={\rm tr\,}A$. Then the equation you have is $\dot x=ax$ has the solution $x(t)=x(t_0)e^{at}$. If $x(t_0)\neq 0$ then $x(t)\neq 0$ for all $t$.

Comment: Oh I see, that makes sense. For iv) I was curious... would the fact that A is skew symmetric and that tr(A) = det(F)'/det(F) mean that Det(F)' and Det(F) be skew-symmetric too. Or would it just be det(F)'/Det(F) thats skew-symmetric? I'm trying to figure out how to do this and my only lead is the fact that for skew-symmetric matrices the transpose equals the negation of the original matrix.